# python: modify text file with raw_input, then continue running script based on what's written to .txt

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

I'm trying to add terminal user-input wrapper around a testing structure that's already been built.

looks like:

> regression_folder:
>
> > r_globals.py [with class r_globals which stores vars]
> >
> > testcases1.py
> >
> > testcases2.py
> >
> > smoketest.py [runs unittest.TestSuite(r_globals.tests_to_run)]
> >
> > regression_runner.py **
> >
> > GLOBALS.txt **

(** indicating files i've added)

all files import r_globals, which stores information necessary for running (like which ip selenium should navigate to).
smoketest uses unittest to run the testcases specified in r_globals

regression_runner is supposed to add functionality s/t a user inputs a list of tests to run (and other configs). then regression_runner calls smoketest, which should run the tests specified by input.

because all files import r_globals, i can't store user inputted configs in there - every import will restore hardcoded values. so currently r_globals reads from GLOBALS.txt, and regression_runner modifies the text file upon user input.

however, currently the GLOBALS.txt is only updated after the script finishes. 
IE:

1. GLOBALS.txt contains 'testcases1' for tests_to_run.
2. run regression_runner, user inputs 'testcases2' for tests_to_run.
3. 'testcases2' is written to GLOBALS.txt. close GLOBALS.txt with
   file.close()
4. regression_runner calls smoketest, which reads from
       r_globals, which reads from GLOBALS.txt.
5. 'testcases1' is run.
6. after script completes, if it's run again w/ no changes THEN 'testcases2' is run.

i've tried all kinds of file.close(), flush(), stdout.flush(), etc. trying reload(r_globals) gives me 'reload argument must be a module'.

can provide code snippets but code is long and split into many files. i know the code structure (using a fake 'globals' file/class) isn't great or pythonic, but refactoring to remove r_globals would require i modify >10 variables in >20 files.

can i get r_globals (and therefore smoketest.py and testcases.py) to pull MODIFIED values from the .txt file in the same instance?

Comment: I might be missing something but couldn't you add a setter and getter in `r_globals.py` and let those two functions be the only functions that read and write files directly? Then you could import it like you already do and call these two functions from all the other scripts